# Using VBA in automating data scraping as well as pressing buttons inside a multi-framed intranet webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vba, excel

I am trying to put a value in a textbox that is within a frame of a company intranet webpage **.aspx** and extract data depending on the value inputted in the textbox. Nothing seems to work, I have tried clicking and changing the dropwdownlist within the login screen using this code `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(1).Value = "optionvalue"` this works. I was able to automatically login in the webpage so I know that `getElements works but after logging in it apparently does not detect the elements in the webpage such as the **textbox** and **dropdownlists**.

Today I found out that the cause of this is because of the multi-frames within the webpage I tried on viewing the source and apparently it is divided to three frames **Banner**, **CSLeftFrame** and **CSMainFrame**.

This is my current code

```
 Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
 Dim objCollection As Object
 ________________________________________________________________________________
 Private Sub AccesLoginLink()
 Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
 IE.navigate "Https://website.aspx"
 IE.visible = true
 PageLoadStart
 End Sub
 ________________________________________________________________________________

 Private Sub automatereview_click()
 If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
 IE.navigate "Https://framewebsite.aspx"
 IE.Visible = True
 PageLoadStart
 IE.document.getElementByTagName("select")(0).Value = "Option in a dropdown"
 ________________________________________________________________________________

 Private Sub PageLoadStart
 While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 End Sub
```

What I did in the code above was access banner frame link that I saw in the view source and that is where I navigated and changed the dropdownoption for testing it apparently worked but what happened was the **BannerFrame** was the only frame that loaded. Is there a way to **Click buttons or input a value in a textbox or scrape data within a frame?**

The reason I am having a hard time is because I am confused as to when I do inspect element in my understanding the **textbox** is in the body of a body class **leftframe** in the frame which has the same frame name and Id of **someLeftPage** and the source is the **CSLeftFrame** which is in an **iframe** which has a name, id, class and source inside the **form** which has a name, id, action and method which is all inside the **frame** in the name of **contentframe** which has a name,id,src.

Here is the pictures for the HTML codes to make it easier for you I highlighted the element tags for the **textbox** and **dropdownlist**. and below here are the inspect element codes for the page.

The SearchBar and **Button** to click is within the **form id** that its action = CSLeftFrame.aspx** within the **body class LeftFrame** which all of them is inside the **iFrame** Which all of the mentioned above is all inside a **Form** that its **action = content.aspx** and inside the frame name called **ContentFrame**.

[image: Page1]
[image: page2]
[image: page3]

Comment: Would have to see the HTML for the site but normally you would use `IE.Document.GetElementsbyTagName("frame")(0)` and add more `GetElements` to narrow down your element.

Comment: And if the site uses javascript you will need to use `.FireEvent ("onClick")` to enable the `.value` change to take effect. for example        `IE.Document.Forms("aspnetForm").Item(ElementID).Value = ObjValue 'Inject value into Form`
       `IE.Document.Forms("aspnetForm").Item(ElementID).FireEvent ("onChange") 'Trigger JavaScript event`

Comment: Your Link is blocked for me. If you want to click a button you just need to use `.click` after your element line.

Comment: @Quint I forgot to mention that the **SearchBar and Button to click** is within the **form id that its action = CSLeftFrame.aspx** within the body class **LeftFrame** which all of them is inside the **iFrame**

Which all of the mentioned above is all inside a **Form that its action = content.aspx** and inside the frame name called **ContentFrame**

Please Help Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Using images to show code is not ideal, and is discouraged in most help forums. Screenshots are marginally better than mobile phone camera pictures, but both are not ideal. It is much better to copy the text of the code you are showing, so you can add it into a formatted code block. Images are not compatible with clipboards, screen readers and search engines, and so make it harder for readers to help. Would you replace those images with the text?

Comment: Additionally, there is a lot of detail in two comments above that looks like it is important enough to add into the question. Would you do that as well? Comments are to ask for clarifications, and is not really for continuing the question material. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer ok thank you will do sorry just new in the forums. Will edit the comments, but for the pictures are currently hard to do so since it is a private company and hard to get the codes. The images are temporary and will change after typing it.

Comment: @Quint Good day! I tried getting the element but still cannot detect the objects still! I think I am getting something wrong. So what I did was get the `IE.document.body.innerHTML` and it only produces '<frame name = "bannerFrame" src = "Banner.aspx"> and <frame name = "contentFrame" src = "content.aspx">'

Answer (score 0):

```
IE.Document.GetElementById("ctlsearch_ddlSearchOptions").value = "NNum" '<----change this to what ever value that is listed.
IE.Document.GetElementById("ctlsearch_ddlSearchOptions").FireEvent ("onchange")
Sleep (2000) '<---- I use a way to pause the script because it can sometimes take so time fot the onchange event to take effect. 

SearchText = "The text that I am seaching for" '<----change this to the text you are searching for.
IE.Document.GetElementById("ctlSearch_txtfind").value = SearchText
```

It's hard to tell without seeing everything if there is multiple frames/tables/forms. So these do not include any sort of hierarchy. If there is you would need to include a `getElementByid()` or a `getElementsByTagName()(0)` after the `.Document`.

Comment: I added images that shows the inspect element sources and deleted the unnecessary images if you need more information just let me know Thanks!